# How to iterate through multiple variables?

Tags: c#, iteration

I'd like to create a short program to download several pictures from a website.

On a form, I would like to enter a root-link to a website with placeholders.
The placeholders can be defined with **Start**/**End** value and **asc**/**desc**.

For example: the original link is

> google.de/1236-01.jpg

and I'd like to generate all links from

> google.de/1236-1.jpg

up to

> google.de/9955-12.jpg

So my input would be **"google.de/[0]-[1].jpg"** and placeholders are set to:

```
[0] = start 1236|end 9955|asc
[1] = start 1|end 12|asc
```

---

Via `GetValidCharacters()` I get a String-List of valid combinations for each entered placeholder (can be selected via ascending/descending + start&end).

The goal I'm struggling with is to build all combinations of this link, because I need to determine while runtime, how much placeholders I have.

My idea was to loop over an queue and `enquueue` each new build line, until there is none left with placeholders, but I don't know how to do this.

I need to make sure that all combinations are entered and they are entered only once.

```
private static void CreateDownloadList()
{
    Queue<string> tmpQueue = new Queue<string>(); //temp queue
    tmpQueue.Enqueue(DL_path); //DL_Path = google.de/[0]-[1].jpg
    string line = "";
    while ((line = tmpQueue.Dequeue()) != null) //not empty
    {
        if (line.Contains("[")) //placeholder
        {
            string tmpLine = line;
            //how to determine, which placeholder is next?? need to know this and replace this with every combination, I get from GetValidCharacters(start, end, DESC)
        }
        else //done
        {
            _urlList.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are working with placeholders, just use `string.Replace("[0]", whatever)`. You could optionally (not really needed, but could be used to stop the loop) use `string.Contains("[10]"`) to check if such placeholder exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going give you the full code but here is some pseudo code that would solve the problem.

given :

```
todostack -- stack object that holds a list of unresolved items

replace_map -- map object that holds marker string and map of all values

marker_list -- list of all markers

final_list -- list object that holds the results
```

(note you can probably use marker_list and replace_map in one object -- I have them separate to make my code clearer)

init :

```
push todostack with your starting string

set marker_list and replace_map to correct values (from parameters I assume)

clear final_list
```

algorithm :

```
 while (there are any items in todostack)
 {       
    curitem = todostack.pop
    if (curitem contains a marker in marker_list)
    {
       loop for each replacement in replace_map
       {
          new_item = curitem replaced with replacement
          todostack.push(new_item)
       }
    }
    else
      add curitem to final_list
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

how about a simple `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 1236; i <= 9955; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
    {
        tmpQueue.Enqueue(string.Format("google.de/{0}-{1}.jpg", i, j)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem described -- the question wants there to be "dynamic" place holders that are passed in.  You won't know how many placeholders or what the values are until runtime.

Comment: but he can pass the ranges by parameters into the method or what kind of dynamic do you mean

Comment: in your code example you have a constant string `google.de/{0}-{1}.jpg` and the constant ranges 1-12 and 1236 to 9955.  What if I want it to do `test{0},{1},{2}` and the ranges 1-5, 3-9 and 1234 to 21345?

Answer (score 0):

@Hogan this was the hint to the correct way.
solution is this

```
private void CreateDownloadList()
        {
            Queue<string> tmpQueue = new Queue<string>();
            tmpQueue.Enqueue(downloadPathWithPlaceHolders);
            while(tmpQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                string currentItem = tmpQueue.Dequeue();
                bool test = false;
                if(currentItem.Contains("["))
                {
                    foreach(Placeholder p in _placeholders)
                    {
                        if(currentItem.Contains(p.PlaceHolder))
                        {
                            foreach(string s in p.Replacements)
                            {
                                tmpQueue.Enqueue(currentItem.Replace(p.PlaceHolder, s));
                            }
                            test = true;
                        }
                        if(test)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _downloadLinkList.Add(currentItem);
                }
            }
        }
```